# Beginner java throws file not found exception? frustrated

Tags: java

Can someone please tell me where i'm going wrong here and the solution, I really dont know why this is giving the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
        at Tutorial6Task1.main(Tutorial6Task1.java:8)"
```

The objective is to read 3 integers from the file, and print them out.

Source Code...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tutorial6Task1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("M:\\eclipse-luna\\Task6\\src\\fileinput1.txt"));
        String firstInt = inFile.nextLine();
        String secondInt = inFile.nextLine();
        String thirdInt = inFile.nextLine();

        inFile.close();

        System.out.println(firstInt);


    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you compiled the file again after adding the throws clause? Do you get any compiler errrors (what you show is a runtime error)?

Comment: Your code compiles fine, sounds like you're compiling the wrong version.  How are you compiling it?  Also, you shouldn't really be using a `FileReader` to read something from within the `src` context, but that's another issue

Comment: I am using Eclipse and running the code through that, the fileinput1.txt is in a referenced library not in src it appears on eclipse, I don't know how it ended up there i did create the text file in the src folder... Thankyou

Comment: Thilo how do i compile the file again again? Thankyou by the way

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not recompiled your class after adding the `throws` clause for `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: How do i recompile the class then? Thank you for the help by the way

Comment: @exactly the same way as you compile. From command line javac your file.java

Comment: But i've been using eclipse to just compile it, If I compiled it with eclipse shouldn't it compile again automatically?

Comment: @paulc01 eclipse compile automatically when it is enabled through menu Project->Build Automatically